# SQL condition CASE in WHERE statement 'THEN NULL'

Tags: sql, null, case, where-clause

I tried to replace value from 'operation_num' if 'column_task' has the particular value. But I cannot find suitable statement. Could you help me?

FYI: column 'operation_num' does not include any NULL value.

```
WHERE
  CASE operation_num WHEN column_task = 'EXERCISE' THEN operation_num is null
                     ELSE operation_num -- operation_num = operation_num
  END
```

Thanks

Comment: The requirement is unclear, at least to me. Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this sample?

Comment: operation_num - 10,20, 30...
column_task - 'EXERCISE', 'RUNNING'...

Comment: In general it's much better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
WHERE
  CASE WHEN column_task = 'EXERCISE' THEN null
                     ELSE operation_num
  END
```

Comment: I see still:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"  ... I tried also .. THEN REPLACE(operation_null, null) but it does not work...

Comment: modified the answer you can check now

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to `AND/OR` (will also have better performance) :

```
WHERE (column_task = 'EXERCISE' and operation IS NULL)
    OR operation_num
```

Though I don't understand the last condition .

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be like below

```
WHERE
  (CASE column_task WHEN 'EXERCISE' THEN  null
                     ELSE operation_num end)= value
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for my wrong question. I solved finally my issue in 'SELECT' part in query:

```
select 
  (case when (to_char(operation_num) = '10' and column_task = 'EXERCISE')
  then REPLACE(to_char(operation_num),'10',' ')
  else to_char(operation__num)
  end) as "column"
  ,column_task
from  my_table
```

But thank you all for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend:

```
WHERE column_task <> 'EXERCISE' OR operation_num IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct ID,
       CASE
          WHEN COLUMN2 is not NULL then COLUM1||'#'|| COLUMN2
           
          ELSE COLUMN1
       END
FROM   table ;
```

this query shows result as column1# which is wrong ,when it's null then it should show column value